# Comparing datetime objects. The right way

Tags: php

What is the right way (best practice) for comparing DateTime objects values in php?
I know that from PHP 5.2.2 and above DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators, but is it a good choice?

Example:

I have two DateTime objects:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime('2016-01-01 15:00:00');
$dt2 = new DateTime('2016-07-10 22:10:00');
```

Should I compare them as objects:

```
$dt1 < $dt2
```

or as timestamps:

```
$dt1->getTimestamp() < $dt2->getTimestamp()
```

?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: `var_dump($dt1); var_dump($dt2);` you will get the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>`, `<` and `==` operators can be reliably used with `DateTime` objects.